# Finding the equation of a polynomial

Tags: functions

A quadratic function with a minimum of 5 has zeros at -4 and 2, find the equation of this function.

This is impossible, correct?

Comment: Yes, seems impossible. Most probably they meant $-5$ for the minimum.

Comment: Or they meant 5 is the MAXimum...

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. It may not have *real* zeroes if the minimum is above zero.

If they meant y=-5 as the minimum, then you could use a matrix to solve for $f(x)$

$y=\frac59x^2+\frac{10}9x+\frac{40}9$

If they meant y=5 is a maximum, then:

$y=\frac{-5}9x^2-\frac{10}9x+\frac{40}9$